# Open image to print in new window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to get this seemingly simple jQuery to work. The plan is to have an external image, which is a smaller version of a large promotional landing page, open in a new window with a print dialog and then close after printing (or canceling). This is the closest I can get it to work ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/paulmz/1r0nxknu/1/)):

```
$('#printBtn').click(function() {
    var couponWindow=window.open('','couponWindow','width=580,height=710');
    couponWindow.focus();
    couponWindow.print();
    couponWindow.close();
});
```

I have tried numerous attempts and variations to open the image into the new window including:

```
var couponWindow=window.open(this.href('http://ecommerce.maurices.com/str/pzTesting/mysteryOffer/coupon.gif'),'couponWindow','width=580,height=710');
```

and

```
var URL = $.myURL("index", $(this).attr('http://ecommerce.maurices.com/str/pzTesting/mysteryOffer/coupon.gif'));
    window.open(URL,'couponWindow','width=580,height=710');
```

All of my attempts to add the image to the window either produces no window, the window opens and closes immediately, or the window opens with the image but doesn't show the print dialog. I have the "coupon" [image hosted externally](http://ecommerce.maurices.com/str/pzTesting/mysteryOffer/coupon.gif) and have also tried with a [basic HTML file](http://ecommerce.maurices.com/str/pzTesting/mysteryOffer/coupon.html) with the image wrapped in a div. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to open up a new window. CSS Print Media is all you need.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("#coupon").off("load").on("load", function() {
    window.print();
  }).attr("src", "http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/images/dog2.jpg");
});
```

```css
body #coupon {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  body * {
    display: none;
  }
  body #coupon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This will not print</p>
<img id="coupon" />
<button>Print coupon</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, espascarello. This worked even better than I planned. I originally didn't want to have to open a new window, but through reading a lot of other posts it seemed necessary. I'm glad there is a way around opening the window. I just had to figure where to put the `<img id="coupon" />`, which worked at the very top of the body.

Comment: Well, this solution did work until I uploaded it to go live. Our hosting company has our entire website "dummied down" to IE7 because they refuse to update their Prototype.js. This constantly limits a lot of what I try to do and definitely makes it difficult to compete with other similar sites that don't have this limitation. So, just a note that **this solution does not work on IE8 or lower due to the CSS media query**. I guess this means back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new HTML file "print-coupon.html" that explicitly invokes the print command and have that HTML file open in a new window.

```
<img src="http://ecommerce.maurices.com/str/pzTesting/mysteryOffer/coupon.gif" />
<script>
    window.print();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hpswddey/

Comment: So, I did end up going with this solution since it appears to work with our site, which is downgraded to IE7 compatibility. Thanks!